# Regex for fixed length string of character A followed by character B

Tags: regex

I'm trying to find a halfway decent regex for a string exactly 8 characters long. Those 8 characters should be comprised of a's followed by b's.

Another way of putting this would be a{n}b{8-n} where n=0...8

Example Matching Strings:
aaaaaaaa
abbbbbbb
aaaabbbb
bbbbbbbb

Example Non-Matching Strings:
bbbbaaaa
aaaabaaa

Comment: I think a regex might be overkill here, there are only 8 possible matches in this case, and there will only ever be n possibilities for all n. Which means o(n) isn't that bad compared to the compute power needed for regexes.

Comment: @Scott Per spec, there's 10 possibilities as can be shown: {"abbbbbbb","aabbbbbb","aaabbbbb","aaaabbbb","aaaaabbb","aaaaaabb","aaaaaaab", "aaaaaaaa","bbbbbbbb", ""}.  Regex could be overkill, but the advantage is the regex can be more quickly altered if the spec changes.

Comment: I think I would recommend (pseudo-code) `/a*b*/ && strlen() == 8`. Maybe do the `strlen()` first for quicker rejections depending on the exact mix of what you're going to feed it...

Comment: @RohitJain I'm using Java

Comment: @Scott Regex may be overkill...but where's the fun in the simple solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways to do it. Here's another alternative:

```
/^(?=a*b*$).{8}$/
```

Of course you can switch around what's in the lookahead:

```
/^(?=.{8}$)a*b*$/
```

Comment: Not exactly a true solution like @acheong87's, but I'd probably do something like `(s.match(/^a*b*$/) && s.length == 8)` where `s` is the string of interest.  Probably the easiest to read.

Comment: @user17753 - That's what I'd do myself.

Comment: Or rather `(s.length == 8 && s.match(/^a*b*$/))` if the EMCA implementation short-circuits?

Comment: @user17753 - It does, though, eh, probably not a worthwhile optimization.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a positive lookahead to limit the length, and otherwise, it's fairly simple.

```
/^(?=[ab]{8}$)a{0,8}b{0,8}$/
```

Comment: Just adding this tidbit in case someone reads this and doesn't realize the syntax:   "The syntax is {min,max}, where min is a positive integer number indicating the minimum number of matches, and max is an integer equal to or greater than min indicating the maximum number of matches." Read [more](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html).

Comment: @Vulcan `?=` is a positive lookahead.

Comment: @Michael Indeed it is, my bad. Thanks Rohit for fixing my mistake.